# getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND registry.npmjs.org registry.npmjs.org:443

Tags: node.js, angular, npm-install

I am working in finance corporate network. Trying to install npm exporter module with npm i mat-table-exporter or xlsx to use export button in angular Material. But I'm getting this error again and again.

> npm ERR! code ENOTFOUND npm ERR! errno ENOTFOUND npm ERR! network
>   request to https://registry.npmjs.org/xlsx failed, reason: getaddrinfo
>   ENOTFOUND registry.npmjs.org registry.npmjs.org:443 npm ERR! network
>   This is a problem related to network connectivity. npm ERR! network In
>   most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.

i tried with checking the config with npm config edit - and is the following details -

> ;;;; ; npm userconfig file ; this is a simple ini-formatted file ;
>   lines that start with semi-colons are comments. ; read `npm help
>   config` for help on the various options ;;;;
>
> strict-ssl=false ;;;; ; all options with default values ;;;; ;
>   access=null ; allow-same-version=false ; always-auth=false ; also=null
>   ; auth-type=legacy ; bin-links=true ; browser=null ; ca=null ;
>   cafile=undefined ; cache=C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache ;
>   cache-lock-stale=60000 ; cache-lock-retries=10 ; cache-lock-wait=10000
>   ; cache-max=null ; cache-min=10 ; cert=null ; cidr=null ; color=true ;
>   depth=null ; description=true ; dev=false ; dry-run=false ;
>   editor=notepad.exe ; engine-strict=false ; force=false ;
>   fetch-retries=2 ; fetch-retry-factor=10 ; fetch-retry-mintimeout=10000
>   ; fetch-retry-maxtimeout=60000 ; git=git ; git-tag-version=true ;
>   commit-hooks=true ; global=false ;
>   globalconfig=C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm\etc\npmrc ;
>   global-style=false ; group=0 ; ham-it-up=false ; heading=npm ;
>   if-present=false ; ignore-prepublish=false ; ignore-scripts=false ;
>   init-module=C:\Users\username.npm-init.js ; init-author-name= ;
>   init-author-email= ; init-author-url= ; init-version=1.0.0 ;
>   init-license=ISC ; json=false ; key=null ; legacy-bundling=false ;
>   link=false ; local-address=undefined ; loglevel=notice ; logs-max=10 ;
>   long=false ; maxsockets=50 ; message=%s ; metrics-registry=null ;
>   node-options=null ; node-version=8.11.3 ; offline=false ;
>   onload-script=null ; only=null ; optional=true ; otp=0 ;
>   package-lock=true ; package-lock-only=false ; parseable=false ;
>   prefer-offline=false ; prefer-online=false ; prefix=C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs ; production=false ; progress=true ; proxy=null ;
>   https-proxy=null ; user-agent=npm/{npm-version} node/{node-version}
>   {platform} {arch} ; read-only=false ; rebuild-bundle=true ;
>   registry=https://registry.npmjs.org/ ; rollback=true ; save=true ;
>   save-bundle=false ; save-dev=false ; save-exact=false ;
>   save-optional=false ; save-prefix=^ ; save-prod=false ; scope= ;
>   script-shell=null ; scripts-prepend-node-path=warn-only ; searchopts=
>   ; searchexclude=null ; searchlimit=20 ; searchstaleness=900
>
> ; send-metrics=false ; shell=C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe ;
>   shrinkwrap=true ; sign-git-tag=false ; sso-poll-frequency=500 ;
>   sso-type=oauth ; strict-ssl=true ; tag=latest ; tag-version-prefix=v ;
>   timing=false ; tmp=C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp ;
>   unicode=false ; unsafe-perm=true ; usage=false ; user=0 ;
>   userconfig=C:\Users\username.npmrc ; umask=0 ; version=false ;
>   versions=false ; viewer=browser ; _exit=true ;
>   globalignorefile=C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm\etc\npmignore

I tried couple of things with previous answer but no success. appreciate your quick help

Comment: What's your node version?  Looks like [quite a few](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22https%3A%2F%2Fregistry.npmjs.org%2Fxlsx%22&oq=%22https%3A%2F%2Fregistry.npmjs.org%2Fxlsx%22&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i58.2574j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) people have had this happen for a variety of reasons.

Comment: node version is v8.11.3